# Magento: adding content managed fields in the backend for a frontend CMS page?

Tags: php, magento

This might be tricky to explain but I'll try my best!

I'm creating fairly basic CMS pages in Magento which are made from standard HTML markup. One of my pages contains a slideshow with different images.

The problem is, every time a designer changes the images, I have to go in and update the image `src` attributes. I've tried to teach the designers and administrators how to edit HTML but many times they have accidentally left out a closing tag, added an extra single quote, etc.

So what I want is the ability to write my markup as normal, but insert "content placeholders" instead of actual content such as image URLs, text snippets, etc.

Then, there would be some extra fields in Magento's backend for that CMS page -- one extra field for each content placeholder I inserted in the markup, above. The non-technical users would then simply write plain text or paste plain URLs in those boxes without having to worry about fiddling about with HTML markup.

So it's like a CMS within a CMS page!

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: +1 for the widget. Pretty easy to build and greatly helps to 'client-proof' CMS pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am told to try a widget. I didn't know widgets offered this functionality but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some free slider available at Magento Connect website.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/

Disclaimer: I am not the owner/staff/affiliate with any of these sliders.